# aggregate value used where an integer was expected -error

Tags: c

i have used the following code as part of a function

```
int encfile(FILE *fin, FILE *fout, aes *ctx, char* fn)
{   char            inbuf[16], outbuf[16];
    fpos_t          flen;

    ...
    fillrand(inbuf, 1);
    ..
    inbuf[0] = ((char)flen & 15) | (inbuf[0] & ~15);
```

i am getting an error

```
aggregate value used where an integer was expected 

     inbuf[0] = ((char)flen & 15) | (inbuf[0] & ~15);
```

Comment: As far as I know, `fpos_t` is not necessarily an integer type. If it's not, then it makes no sense to use bitwise operators on it.

Answer (score 1):

`fpos_t` is type that is implementation defined. It is just guaranteed to be a non array type. Meaning it could be a struct (which seems to the problem in your case).

Either way, `fpos_t` is supposed to be used only with `fsetpos` and `fgetpos`. You are not supposed to perform any operations with it.

For your case, if you need to know the length of the file you should use [`fstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat).

Other wise if you do not have access to the file name, you can use -

```
long int old_position = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long int flen = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, old_position, SEEK_SET);
```

This also doesn't break portability because [`fseek`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm) and [`ftell`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_ftell.htm) are part of the C standard.